# How to filter boolean field with enum?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core application.

And I have a repository with a query-method in it. And I have `AlertStatusEnum`, like this:

```
public enum AlertStatusEnum
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Alerts where done is true
    /// </summary>
    Done = 1,
    /// <summary>
    /// Alerts where done is false
    /// </summary>
    NotDone,
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns complete list of Alerts either done or NotDone
    /// </summary>
    All
}
```

and I have a query method like this:

```
public async Task<List<Alert>> GetAllAlertsForOrganisation(int organisationId, DateTime? beginDate, DateTime? endDate, AlertStatusEnum statusEnum)
{
    return await GetAlerts(i => i.OrganisationId == organisationId 
        && (endDate == null || i.CreatedAt <= endDate) 
        && (beginDate == null || i.CreatedAt >= beginDate)
        && i.IsDone)
       .ToListAsync();           
}
```

and `IsDone` looks like this:

```
   public bool IsDone { get; set; }
```

So the only thing I want that is following:

- If `statusEnum`-parameter is `AlertStatusEnum.Done`, return only Alerts which have `IsDone`==true
- If `statusEnum`-parameter is `AlertStatusEnum.NotDone`, return only Alerts which have `IsDone`==false
- If `statusEnum`-parameter is `AlertStatusEnum.All`, return all alerts despite `IsDone`-property's value.

But how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. At the moment I'm finding it hard to understand your question. What do you mean by "if Done is selected from the enum"? Selected where? As the `statusEnum` parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With following snippet you can filter data based on `statusEnum`-parameter:

```
public async Task<List<Alert>> GetAllAlertsForOrganisation(int organisationId, DateTime? beginDate, DateTime? endDate, AlertStatusEnum statusEnum)
{
    var isDone = statusEnum == AlertStatusEnum.Done; 
    return await GetAlerts(i => i.OrganisationId == organisationId 
        && (endDate == null || i.CreatedAt <= endDate) 
        && (beginDate == null || i.CreatedAt >= beginDate)
        && (i.IsDone == isDone || statusEnum == AlertStatusEnum.All))
       .ToListAsync();           
}
```